# Create a model with google ML natural language or other potential service

Tags: google-cloud-ml, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit, google-natural-language

So I have been collecting **data of** numerous **text**-descriptions about articles, where as each description was structred differently. Now, I would have to "create" an **algorithm**, which sorts out the title of that article for me what is a hard task. I have come around **Google ML natural language** and it seems to be able to create one for me.
Unfortunately, I am not really able to exactly find out how I can use it,

so my question is... How precisely can I set it up ? And additionally, it would be helpful to know if **firebase** has such a service, since I am planning to build a firebase project.

Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: Are you creating the project for mobile?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, but if that helps - yes Im going to create a mobile app

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately models created using Google AutoML Natural Language are not exportable to Tensorflow lite (mobile models). Based from your use case you will need a model for [text classification](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples/text_classification/overview), the provided link has a sample of how this model work. You can follow this [tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/g3doc/tutorials/model_maker_text_classification.ipynb) to train a custom model using the data that you have so it can identify if a title of a article is a hard task or not.

Once training is done you can now:

1. Deploy it in Firebase
2. Download the model in your device and perform testing.

You can find detailed instructions from training the model to testing it on your device for either [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml/ios/use-custom-models) or [android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml/android/use-custom-models).

Comment: @AJ.beProgramming If my answer was useful, click the upvote button (▲) to the left of it (you may not yet have enough reputation for this). If it answered your question, click the checkmark (✓) to accept it (once the system allows that). That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped. Also see [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?